# Create a calendar table

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a calendar table for a full year starting lets say from 30/06/2014 to 30/06/2015. Also have 15 values of a variable that should be assigned to each one of those days in that year in a way:
Column1=C1, Column2=C2

```
C1  C2
0   30/06/2014
0   01/07/2014
0   02/07/2014
.    .
.    .
0   30/06/2015
3   30/06/2014
3   01/07/2014
3   02/07/2014
.   .
.   .
3   30/06/2015
123 30/06/2014
123 01/07/2014
123 02/07/2014
.   .
.   .
123 30/06/2015
```

So ideally my table would look like this. 15 values times 366 days = 5490 rows.

I have created an array with my values valuearry that could be useful for iterations.

```
StartDate = #6/30/2014#
For i = 1 To 366
   j = 4

        Cells(i, 2) = StartDate
        StartDate = DateAdd("d", 1, StartDate)
        Cells(i, 1) = valuearray(j)

Next i
```

I change manually the value of J since I couldn't find a proper way for automating this process. Any ideas of how I should arrange my loops and iterations to automate this process?

Comment: What are your 15 values? is there some hierarchy between them?

Comment: No, there is not link between the values, more like names than anything else.

Comment: In that case, put all of your values in array and put an additional loop for this array. if you need help with that, add all your variables to the question.

Comment: I've tried that but couldn't find the correct configuration of the loops. Could you please give me an example of how to do it with  3 dummy values and I will adjust that to my values. v1=10, v2=30, v3=50 ( there's no link between the values, pick random values if you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have  added one more loop for your code with array. see below:

```
Sub myArray()

'
Dim my(1 To 3) As Long
my(1) = 10
my(2) = 30
my(3) = 50



For k = 1 To 3

StartDate = #6/30/2014#
For i = 1 To 366


        Cells((i + (k * 366)) - 366, 2) = StartDate

        Cells((i + (k * 366) - 366), 1) = my(k)



        StartDate = DateAdd("d", 1, StartDate)


Next i
Next k
'
End Sub
```